# Updating canvas image when image.src has a timetag

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

with this code I try to update a canvas with a drawn image when imageUpdated is true. 
I use a timetag so the image isnt loaded from the browser cache.
But when i use timetags the canvas stays empty.
It works without the timetags.

```
var imageUpdated = true;
if(imageUpdated) 
{
  imageUpdated = false; 
  var heightImg = new Image;
  heightImg.src = '/path/to/image.png?' + new Date().getTime().toString();
  this.canvas = $('<canvas />')[0];
  this.canvas.width = this.width;
  this.canvas.height = this.height;
  this.canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(heightImg, 0, 0, this.width, this.height);
}
/*rest of event happens here*/
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it's because you're drawing the image before it is loaded. 
I guess that's also the reason it works without the timetag, it's already in cache so can instantly be drawn.

A solution would be to draw after the image is loaded. So, add an eventListener on the image:

```
image.addEventListener('load', callback);
```

Within the callback, draw the image on the canvas.

For example:

```
// add eventlistener
heightImg.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
    var width = heightImg.width;
    var height = heightImg.height;

    var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;

    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(heightImg, 0, 0, width, height); 
});

// trigger the loading
heightImg.src = url + '?time=' + new Date().getTime().toString();
```

And a **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zn483mak/1/)**